# processing a file after a string has been matched in it

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a json file I am doing some processing on, I had to pause the operation and I want to start the processing again where I left, this is the code I am using, the problem is the If condition still executes even if the While loops condition isn't met, from my understanding the code should be unreachable until the While loop doesn't meet it's condition. Where am I going wrong?

```
row_counter = 0
start_now = 0
Finished = 0
with open('jsonfile') as f:
    for row in f:
        row_counter += 1
        if row_counter > start_now:
            try:
                row = json.loads(row)
                comment_id = row['id']

                while Finished == 0:
                    if (comment_id != 'The_String_I_Wanna_Match'):
                        Finished = True
                        break

                if (condition):
                    print('code i want to execute')
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
        if (row_counter % 100000 == 0):
            print('no. of rows gone by {}'.format(row_counter))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what makes you think your code is unreachable. I'm also not sure how you're not getting trapped in an infinite loop. That `while Finished == 0 ...` should never exit unless the first json row contains the string you're trying to match. Regardless, assuming the first row does have your string your condition is immediately called because your while loop breaks out.

Comment: Also, as a best practices reminder: Don't use capitalized variable names and if you're going to do a conditional you can use booleans and thus `while not finished:` would function fine.

Comment: could you help me out with a sample code that you would right? It would really help me out I have been stuck on this for the entire day. @MCBama

Comment: Ok so i figured out while you're not in an infinite loop. are you intending to do a `!=` on your string match? If you want to check if `comment_id` matches your string that needs to be a `==` which also explains why you're immediately breaking out since the first line probably doesn't have the string you're looking for in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
while finished == False:
    if (comment_id == 'commentid'):
        finished = True

if (finished == True):
    pass
```

Comment: `Flase` really?

Comment: from the source code provided I thought it'd work best, what would you do?

Comment: Ohhh that! Apologies I didn't even notice.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do here since you posted mostly pseudo code but you definitely don't want to use a while loop. A while loop there will lock your program if the first line happens to match the string you're looking for forever (unless you're running multi-threaded but you don't seem to be). I also think you're using the wrong conditional operator there but as I said, not 100% sure what you're going for here.

This is what I think you're going to need:

```
import json

row_counter = 0
start_now = 0

with open('file.json') as f:
  for row in f:
    row_counter += 1
    if row_counter > start_now:
      try:
        # check to ensure we're not messing with a blank row
        if not row: continue

        # load the row. This line might throw an exception if the 
        # line isn't perfect json
        row = json.loads(row)
        print(row)
        comment_id = row['id']

        if(comment_id == 'The_String_I_Wanna_Match'):
          print('Execute code here')

      except Exception as e:
        import traceback
        print(traceback.print_exc())
    if (row_counter % 100000 == 0):
      print('no. of rows gone by {}'.format(row_counter))
```